# Any way to fix this spacing without style attribute? Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/TtYtS/8/

```
<div class="indent input-prepend pull-right" style="margin:2px 0 0 20px">
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Search by brand name">
</div>
```

The search box lines up (vertically) with the menu items because of the style attribute I added. It also created some spacing between them.

Is there any way to accomplish both of these without that style attribute or creating my own class?

Comment: Why don't you wanna add your own class?

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing

```
<div class="indent input-prepend pull-right" style="margin:2px 0 0 20px">
```

to
    `<div class="input-prepend offset1">`

Comment: I thought about that but offset1 can be rather large depending on responsive state. :(

Comment: Thats true. try with `<div class="span3 input-prepend pull-right">`